# How can i get the messages from firestore with using Changenotifier

Tags: flutter

Im new user and programmer.I need some help.
My problem is getting messages in firestore.

I use the ChangeNotifierProvider in my Main with my firestore.dart file which has this code:

```html
class FireBaseData with ChangeNotifier {
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<void> signIn({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      e.message;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> signUp({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      e.message;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future getMessageToFirestore() async {
    await _firestore.collection('messages').get();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void writeMessageToFirestore({String textFromUser}) {
    _firestore.collection('messages').add({'mesaj': textFromUser});
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I try to call in my Text just like that:

Text(${Provider.of(context).getMessageToFirestore}

I know it is not true but i do not know how can i use it. Maybe i use wrong type the others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are going about this the entirely wrong way

Your firestore can Stream your data. StreamBuilder widget will give you the ability to subscribe to the stream and build your underlying widgets

This video is a good guide
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqJ_KjFzL9I

Good luck on your flutter journey

Comment: i do not know how can i mention you but thanks a lot, that's it..